# php framework for interactions with OpenLayers

Tags: php, openlayers

What is the most dedicated  ?
I tested the drupal openlayers module but it seems limited for my project.

I'm looking at CakePhp, Symphony and Zend.
Somebody has an experience with one of those ?

Thank's

Comment: Maybe you should describe a bit more what you are trying to build.

Answer (score 1):

I love Yii Framework, and there is a widget for OpenLayers

Yii Framework:
www.yiiframework.com

Widget:
http://code.google.com/p/yii-openlayers/

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/yii-openlayers/ is empty
Here is enother one widget for Yii:
https://bitbucket.org/coxa/yii-open-layers-widget